# Android Gradle method to add sourcesets

Tags: java, android, gradle, source-sets

Currently I am developing an app with gradle and I have lots of different `sourcesets` for some different flavors. I am adding `sourcesets` in my `build.gradle` the following way:

```
sourceSets {
        debug {
            java.srcDirs += ['src/firstLib/common/java']
        }
        release {
            java.srcDirs += ['src/firstLib/common/java']
        }
}
```

Because I have lots of this blocks in my `build.gradle` I was wondering if there is an possibility to simply call a function which takes the `sourcesets` as a parameter and add it to the `java.srcDirs`. For example something like this:

```
void addToSourceSet(String parameter) {
    sourceSets {
        debug {
            java.srcDirs += [parameter]
        }
        release {
            java.srcDirs += [parameter]
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible even if the method body isn't part of the gradle android-tag?

Comment: It is possible, however you need to pass an instance of `Project` class as well, and invoke `sourceSets` on it. Otherwise it will not work.